# Replace an existing image with another

Tags: javascript, html, image

I'm trying to build a simple Javascript to drag and drop an image. 
The dragged image after being dragged and dropped should regenerate in its original position. 
I'm trying something like this, but it seems to not work; it doesn't regenerate the picture:

My js function:

```
var nPedY = 21;
var nPedR = 21;
var red = new Image(50,50);
red.src = "red.png";

function allowDrop(ev) {
ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    if (data == "drag1"){
        document.getElementById("drag1").src = red.src;
        console.log(nPedR);
    }
}
```

And my HTML markup:

```
<tr>
<td width="50px" height="50px"><img id="drag1" src="red.png" align="center" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"></td>
<td width="50px" height="50px"><img id="drag2" src="yellow.png" align="center" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"></td>
</tr>
```

Can anyone give me an hint? thanks.

Comment: You are getting any error?

Comment: You need to clone the element and drop

Comment: "*[After] being dragged and dropped...*" where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true));
}
```

Once you clone the element, only a copy of it will be added to the droppable.

Comment: And for avoiding the image to regenerate if a counter values is zero? thanks in advance.

Comment: Check for the counter and remove / hide the element